# Implementing Dynamic Island support - Generic parameter 'Expanded' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, widgetliveactivity, dynamic-island

I'm following [Displaying live data with Live Activities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities) and adding support for the Dynamic Island in an app with an existing widgets extension. However, I'm unable too get it to build

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit


@main
struct PizzaDeliveryActivityWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: PizzaDeliveryAttributes.self) { context in
            // Create the presentation that appears on the Lock Screen and as a
            // banner on the Home Screen of devices that don't support the
            // Dynamic Island.
            // ...
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            // Create the presentations that appear in the Dynamic Island.
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

as I get the errors

```
Generic parameter 'Expanded' could not be inferred
```

and

```
Result builder 'DynamicIslandExpandedContentBuilder' does not implement any 'buildBlock' or a combination of 'buildPartialBlock(first:)' and 'buildPartialBlock(accumulated:next:)' with sufficient availability for this call site
```

This is even if I supply a `dynamicIsland` closure of

```
            DynamicIsland {
                EmptyView()
            } compactLeading: {
                EmptyView()
            } compactTrailing: {
                EmptyView()
            } minimal: {
                EmptyView()
            }
```

What am I missing? My project's minimum deployment target is iOS 16.1.

Comment: Well you only have comments in your code... You should have at least a `DynamicIslandExpandedRegion` in your `DynamicIsland`. Did you read the whole guide you linked? It shows how to do this further down the page.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by adding the following above the widget declaration
@available(iOS 16.2, *)

(Yes 16.2), it has something to do with the context.isStale bit.